# Check radio button by default in a radio button group list in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, radiobuttonlist

I am using Angular 7 and HTML. I am facing a problem with checked a default radio button when loading the page. I am able to get value but can't able to checked a radio button when loading the page. Please, anyone, guide me how to solve this.

**[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radiobuttonlist-for-html?file=app%2Fbuttons-checkbox.html)**

// my ts file

```
paymentModeStatus: string;
selectedValueForPaymentModeChange = 'cash';
paymentModeList: any = [];

public constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPaymentModeList();
}
getPaymentModeList() {
  this.paymentModeList = [{
      'checked': true,
      'name': 'Cash',
      'value': 'cash',
    },
    {
      'checked': false,
      'name': 'Pay to Accounts',
      'value': 'accounts',
    }
  ];
}
```

// my html file

```
<div style="font-weight: bold">Payment Mode:</div>

<label 
  style="padding: 0 5px 0 20px" 
  *ngFor="let paymentMode of paymentModeList">
  <input 
    type="radio" 
    name="paymentMode" 
    required="false"
    [(ngModel)]="paymentModeStatus" 
    [value]="paymentMode.name"
    (click)="paymentModeStatusAction(paymentMode.value)"             
    [checked]='paymentMode.checked'>
    {{paymentMode.name}}
</label>
<pre>{{ paymentModeStatus }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you've specified `[(ngModel)]="paymentModeStatus"` and `[value]="paymentMode.name"`, you'll have to set the `paymentModeStatus` as the `name` of whichever payment mode you want to set as default.

Just add this to your `ngOnInit`

```
this.paymentModeStatus = this.paymentModeList[0].name;
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radiobuttonlist-for-html-arvkqn?file=app/buttons-checkbox.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the *Checked* attribute does not require a value

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

As long as the check attribute exists, the element will be checked.

*From above link*

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**
I have modified your html [buttons-checkbox.html] to displayed default checked by using the code below

```
<style>
  label {
    padding: 0 5px 0 20px
  }
</style>

<div><b>Payment Mode:</b></div>

  <label *ngFor="let paymentMode of paymentModeList">

    <input 
      type="radio" 
      name="paymentMode" 
      required="false" 
      [(ngModel)]="paymentModeStatus" 
      [checked]="paymentMode.checked == 'true'"
    />

    {{paymentMode.name}} {{paymentMode.checked}}

  </label>

<pre>{{ paymentModeStatus }}</pre>
```

Comment: Please also suggest how would one achieve what OP is looking for with an `*ngFor` in their template.

Comment: Edited (I see why this is will be v. useful for OP) thanks!